# How to make webpack case sensitive

Tags: node.js, webpack

I need to support files with similar names, but different casing in my build.
Currently, webpack checks all file names with `checkSimilarFile` function, which is case insensitive and throws an error: `Prevent writing to file that only differs in casing or query string from already written file. This will lead to a race-condition and corrupted files on case-insensitive file systems.`
Is there a way to achieve it?

*case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin* is not what I need, as I understand it works with imports.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.